# Get information from XML with python

Tags: python, xml

I have this XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList- 
1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
   <dict>
      <key>arm64</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>artistId</key>
...
  <key>genre</key>
  <string>Travel</string>
  <key>genreId</key>
  <integer>6003</integer>
  <key>itemId</key>
  <integer>1260842311</integer>
</dict>
```

How can I get the last integer to get the `itemID` with python ?

> 1260842311

Comment: This xpath expression works: `//key[.="itemId"]/following-sibling::integer/text()`

Comment: I get an AttributeError with this code : for user in tree.xpath("//key[.='itemId']/following-sibling::integer/text()"):
    print(user.text)

Answer (score 0):

A quick approach would be using *ElementTree* with an XPath-1.0 expression:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET 
lastInt = ET.parse('input.xml').findall("dict/integer[last()]")
for i in lastInt: 
  print i.text
```

`ET.parse` sets the context to the root element of the XML named `plist`. Then `findall` selects the last `integer` child of the `dict` element. The `for` then iterates over the last `integer` elements of each `dict` element found.